# Python regex. Match and replace roman numerals

Tags: python, regex, roman-numerals

Need some help with regular expressions.
I want to match some Roman numerals and replace them to arabic.

First of all if use `(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})` to match roman numerals (from 1 to 9).
Then i add some logic to either space (with some text before) or nothing (begin/end of string) with `(?:^|\s)(?:\s|$)`

So finaly i've `(?:^|\s)(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(?:\s|$)`

It matches all this variants:

1. some text VI
2. IX here we are
3. another III text

If i define dict with roman-arabic map `{'iii': 3, 'IX': 9}` - how to repalce matches with values from dict? Also it matches only first accur, i.e. in `some V then III` i get only `V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also it matches only first accur, i.e. in some V then III i get only V

I assume that you are using `re.match` or `re.search` which is only giving you one result. We will use `re.sub` to solve your main question so this won't be an issue. `re.sub` can take a callable. We replace any match with the corresponding value from your dictionary. Use

```
re.sub(your_regex, lambda m: your_dict[m.group(1)], your_string)
```

This assumes any possible match is in your `dict`. If not, use

```
re.sub(your_regex, lambda m: your_dict[m.group(1)] if m.group(1) in your_dict else m.group(1), your_string)
```

Comment: It works, but i've mistake in regex. With roman numerals spaces are removed too. `star wars IV` is converted to `star wars4` or `some III text` to `some3text`

Comment: @DigitalGod add optional spaces in your matching group 1, example: https://regex101.com/r/zA7lX5/1

Comment: I do not know much about regular expressions, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your example doesn't work as expected. It fetches both `_III_` and `III`.

Comment: Sorry my example was a bit rushed and I'm in a hurry. I answered assuming you had the regex figured out and wanted to know how to do the replacing. Maybe you should open a new question asking for the regex needed itself, or if you want to I will delete my answer.

Comment: No problem. I'll create another question :)